# Unable to add user to verdaccio registry

Tags: npm, verdaccio, npm-registry

I am trying to publish scoped package to verdaccio registry . I installed verdaccio by following commands

> npm install -g verdaccio

Added this in my package.json file

```
   "publishConfig": {
   "registry": "http://localhost:4873"
    }
```

After that i tried to add user by following command

> npm adduser --registry http://localhost:4873

But i am getting the error and also not able to publish it .
[image]

Can anyone help me how can i publish it ?

Comment: Are you running verdaccio? I don’t see the prove is running. That is what the error suggest.

Answer (score -1):

Run `verdaccio` first.

Open new terminal tab, then you should be able to run
`npm adduser --registry http://localhost:4873`